# How can I create a custom bazel build rule that uses the runfiles path of another rule?

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to create a custom build rule to build a pip package from a py_binary output. To create my pip package I want to invoke a shell script. The shell script builds a pip package by creating a zip file from the runfiles of the py_binary output.

For example suppose I have

```
py_binary(
    name = "some_binary",
    srcs = ["some_binary.py"],
    srcs_version = "PY2AND3",
)
```

Building this rule produces

```
bazel-bin/some_binary.runfiles
```

I would now like to create a custom build rule that will invoke my shell script with the location bazel-bin/some_binary.runfiles

I tried creating a macro

```
def build_pip_package(
    name, py_binary=None, setup_file=None):
  """Create a pip package from a py_binary.

  The source file should be a text file with python formatting i.e.

  Args:
    name: Name for the rule.
    py_binary: Build rule producing the py_binary
    setup_file: Build rule producing the setup.py file to use to produce
      the package.
  """
  output= "somefile"
  native.genrule(
      name=name,
      outs=[output],
      cmd="echo $(location //:build_pip_package_script) "
      + "--py_runfiles_path=$(locations %s)" % py_binary
      + " --setup_file=$(location %s) " % setup_file,
      tools=["//:build_pip_package_script"],
      srcs=[setup_file, py_binary])
```

This ends up invoking my shell script with

```
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/some_binary/model_train some_binary.py
```

How can I invoke my script with the location of the runfiles directory corresponding to the some_binary target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put the py_binary in the tools attribute instead of srcs bazel will include the runfiles tree. You can access it via `"$(location %s).runfiles" % py_binary`